# Change android editText highlight color

Tags: android-layout, android-edittext

Does anyone know how can I change this green color that appears in my editText ?

I would like to do it from the layout XML if it is possible 
just below the editText image.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could resolve it adding: `android:backgroundTint="@color/color_you_wat"` to the EditText in the layout file

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically:

```
  editText.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Using theme:

```
<style name="AppThem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <!-- change values below to make same eefect for all EditTexts ->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accent</item>
</style>
<!-- also you can create different styles with values above for many different views ->
```

**Edit:**

You can always use in `xml` file:

`"app:backgroundTint="@color/myColor"` in `xml`.

Don't use `android:`. Otherwise you would lose backward compability with Android 4.4 and older.

Hope it help

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work for me, once I click this editText to set the email, this green color is appeared I don't know where it come from